# Cannot get validation to work when extending shared code in Asp.Net MVC 4 via RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I work with a lot of shared code and sometimes I need to try and extend functionality without altering the existing solution. I have adopted a kind of pattern (or is it an anti-pattern?) that allows to add sort of 'widgets' but it doesn't quite work with validation.

**Scenario**

I have an existing shared controller, view model, validator (fluent validation) and view.  I want to add a text box to the view that seems to be part of the shared page from a user point of view without changing any of the shared code. I can achieve what I want except for validation on the added text box.

**Solution**

I create a controller, view model, validator and partial view for my widget.  I then use a strongly typed RenderAction like this within the shared view:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction<MyWidgetController>(x => x.Execute()); }
```

**Widget Code**

**View Model**

```
[Validator(typeof(WidgetValidator))]    
public class Widget
{        
    public int? WidgetTest{ get; set; }        
}
```

**Widget Validator**

```
public class TestValidator : AbstractValidator<WidgetViewModel>
{
    public TestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.WidgetTest).GreaterThan(-1).WithValidationResource("Widget_Error");
    }
}
```

**Widget Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Execute()
    {           
        return PartialView("_widget", model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Execute(WidgetViewModel model)
    {                              
        return PartialView("_widget", model);
    }
```

The partial view is inside the form tag and will perform server side validation but only if the shared model is also valid.

Otherwise, the page will be seen as valid and will move on, presumably because the shared page is valid and so redirects.

Is there anyway that I can make this widget validate as part of the page it is added to without changing code in the shared controller or view model?

Or, is this just a bad idea and is there a better way to achieve extension?

Thanks in advance